How does XGBoost aggregate models being trained in a distributed fashion across n machines?
I am trying to understand how XGBoost distributed training works. The best explanation I've found so far is in this paper: https://ml-pai-learn.oss-cn-beijing.aliyuncs.com/%E6%9C%BA%E5%99%A8%E5%AD%A6%E4%B9%A0%E8%B5%84%E6%96%99/LearningSys_2015_paper_32.pdf
What I am struggling to understand is when and how models between instances (machines) are synced. Is it the case that at every split on every tree in the model, the training machines communicate so that the same split is created across instances? Or is it the case that each instance builds its own tree and then the trees are synchronized? If it is the latter, how does this tree synchronization happen?
